# Complicated nested loops

Tags: php, loops, charts, d3.js

I'm trying to do some data visualization with a db.

At first I used morris.js, which worked great with my data. I'll explain more right after.
I'm now trying to use d3.js, since I have to create horizontal stacked bars, multiple chart lines, and more …

This is my table : http://d.pr/i/ooDN 
(I don't have 10 reputations, I can't post my picture)

I have to draw 5 different lines on the chart. "Heure" being the x-axis, the other columns being the different lines.

With morris, my datas were like this (r_print in JSON at the end of the .php `[{"x":"1","a":"34","b":"15","c":"49","d":"15","e":"3"},`
`{"x":"2","a":"36","b":"13","c":"49","d":"12","e":"2"}, … ]`

Where x is the time data (and the x-axis, and the a-e letters are others line dots for each hours.)

But with d3.js, those arrays do not work anymore, and I got to change my php to obtain something like this :

`[{"x": 1, "y": 5}, { "x": 2, "y": 20}, { "x": 3,  "y": 10}, … , { "x": 23, "y": 60}]`

`[{"x": 1, "y": 13}, { "x": 2, "y": 14}, { "x": 3,  "y": 5}, … , { "x": 23, "y": 48}]`

Where each line is a different column.

This is my php :

```
<?php include 'connexion.php' ?>

<?php
////////////////// out_evo_tat   
$requete = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM out_evo_tat');
$requete->execute();

while($row = $requete->fetch()) { 

    // $tableau[]=array('x'=>$row['Heure'],'a'=>$row['TAT_CHAINE'],'b'=>$row['TAT_PREA'],'c'=>$row['TAT_GLOBAL'],'d'=>$row['NBR_TESTS'], 'e'=>$row['NBR_TUBES'] );
    // $tableau[]=array($row['Heure'],$row['TAT_CHAINE'],$row['TAT_PREA'],$row['TAT_GLOBAL'],$row['NBR_TESTS'], $row['NBR_TUBES'] );

    $tableau[]= array (
        array($row['Heure'],$row['TAT_CHAINE']),
        array($row['Heure'], $row['TAT_PREA']),
        array($row['Heure'], $row['TAT_GLOBAL']),
        array($row['Heure'], $row['NBR_TESTS']),
        array($row['Heure'], $row['NBR_TUBES'])
        );  
}

echo json_encode($tableau);

?>
```

How can I modify this code above to obtain something usable with d3.js ?

I think i have to use nested loops but I can't solve it by myself …

I tried to explain it the easiest way but it is maybe difficult to understand as I explained, so do not hesitate to ask me more.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've generated your array as shown in your PHP code, the following uses that array to produce an array of JSON strings:

```
array_unshift($tableau, null);
$tableau = call_user_func_array('array_map', $tableau);
$json = array();
foreach ($tableau as $key => $val){
    $out = array();
    foreach ($val as $key2 => $val2){
        $item = new stdClass;
        $item->x = $val2[0];
        $item->y = $val2[1];
        $out[] = $item;
    }
    $json[] = json_encode($out);
}
print_r($json);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [{"x":0,"y":35},{"x":1,"y":34},{"x":2,"y":36},{"x":3,"y":35}]
    [1] => [{"x":0,"y":10},{"x":1,"y":15},{"x":2,"y":13},{"x":3,"y":15}]
    [2] => [{"x":0,"y":45},{"x":1,"y":49},{"x":2,"y":49},{"x":3,"y":50}]
    [3] => [{"x":0,"y":10},{"x":1,"y":15},{"x":2,"y":12},{"x":3,"y":5}]
    [4] => [{"x":0,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":3},{"x":2,"y":2},{"x":3,"y":1}]
)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I doubt at first side but this works ! But now I got to understand how works d3 …

Comment: You're welcome. The first two lines of the code do a matrix transform which essentially turns a matrix on its side. That's a very useful maneuver when working with arrays.

Comment: I'll remember this, thanks a lot. Do you know d3.js ? I got more problems with it, should I ask them here (since I use those shown datas) or should I create another post ?

Comment: @MathieuLuyten - I don't know anything about d3.js, so another post would probably be your best bet.

Comment: Since I have problems with d3, I try to use another librairy. 
Do you have any advices for that choice ?
Since I'll have to create stacked bars and multiple lines charts, I'm now trying to use http://www.ejschart.com/
Could you help me editing your code so the JSON follows the [required format (link)](http://www.jscharts.com/how-to-use-multiple-data-series)  ?

Comment: [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) looks actually way better for my needs …

Answer (score 0):

I think google have a lot of APIs to create charts... 
i found this one:[Populating Data Using Server-Side Code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example?hl=pt-BR&csw=1)

PS:Im not a PHP programmer...i know a little only.

I think it will help you ...